# how can i import and use a local .csv file in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, csv, nuxt.js, vite

i have a csv file in this structure

```
name,year,href,src
Parasite,2019,parasite-2019,film-poster/4/2/6/4/0/6/426406-parasite-0-460-0-690-crop.jpg
```

i would like to import this file as a list with each line as a dict in this way:

```js
[{'name':'Parasite','year':'2019','href':'parasite-2019','src':'film-poster/4/2/6/4/0/6/426406-parasite-0-460-0-690-crop.jpg'}]
```

i tried using `import csv from './filmList.csv'` inside the `<script>` tag, but that only gives me an error on load:

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. You may need to install appropriate plugins to handle the .csv file format.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install [`@rollup/plugin-dsv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-dsv) as a dev dependency:

```
npm i -D @rollup/plugin-dsv
```

...and configure Vite to use it:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import dsv from '@rollup/plugin-dsv' 

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    dsv(), 
  ],
})
```

Then importing a `.csv` file would produce the object array, as you were expecting:

```html
<script>
// MyComponent.vue
import csv from './filmList.csv'
console.log(csv) // => [{'name':'Parasite','year':'2019','href':'parasite-2019','src':'film-poster/4/2/6/4/0/6/426406-parasite-0-460-0-690-crop.jpg'}]
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-load-csv?file=vite.config.js)