# Illegal tag name. Use '&lt;' to print '<'. on nuxt project

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3

so i have a nuxt3 project thats using a rollup plugin called dsv, and i think have installed vite wrong in the project or something, cause when i try to build it to production it gives me an error, heres the [github](https://github.com/darkitow/lboxd-roulette) project if it helps, i have no idea why this is happening

i tried removing the vue plugin on the vite config but i get different error `Cannot split a chunk that has already been edited (119:17 – "', { enumerable: false, value: true })` when building to production, but i dont get any when using `npm run dev`, as i do when i have it

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import dsv from '@rollup/plugin-dsv'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    dsv(),
  ],
})
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
 ERROR  Illegal tag name. Use '&lt;' to print '<'.                                                            11:58:36


 ERROR  [vite:vue] Unquoted attribute value cannot contain U+0022 ("), U+0027 ('), U+003C (<), U+003D (=), and U+0060 (`).
file: C:/Users/maia/Desktop/lboxdroulette/nuxt-app/app.vue:22:64


 ERROR  Unquoted attribute value cannot contain U+0022 ("), U+0027 ('), U+003C (<), U+003D (=), and U+0060 (`).

  at createCompilerError (node_modules\@vue\compiler-core\dist\compiler-core.cjs.prod.js:18:19)
  at emitError (node_modules\@vue\compiler-core\dist\compiler-core.cjs.prod.js:1566:29)
  at parseAttributeValue (node_modules\@vue\compiler-core\dist\compiler-core.cjs.prod.js:1454:13)
  at parseAttribute (node_modules\@vue\compiler-core\dist\compiler-core.cjs.prod.js:1330:17)
  at parseAttributes (node_modules\@vue\compiler-core\dist\compiler-core.cjs.prod.js:1286:22)
  at parseTag (node_modules\@vue\compiler-core\dist\compiler-core.cjs.prod.js:1175:17)
  at parseElement (node_modules\@vue\compiler-core\dist\compiler-core.cjs.prod.js:1104:21)
  at parseChildren (node_modules\@vue\compiler-core\dist\compiler-core.cjs.prod.js:933:28)
  at Object.baseParse (node_modules\@vue\compiler-core\dist\compiler-core.cjs.prod.js:848:23)
  at Object.parse (node_modules\@vue\compiler-dom\dist\compiler-dom.cjs.prod.js:3034:25)
```

tried [kissu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72078992/17089968) but now im getting a different error when tring to build for production, which i mentioned i got when altering the vite config file, still not sure why, but when using for dev it doesn't give any erros anymore

```js
// nuxt.config.ts
// @ts-nocheck
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'
import dsv from '@rollup/plugin-dsv'
 
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    vite: {
        plugins: [dsv()]
    },
    modules: ['@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'],
    build: {
        postcss: {
            postcssOptions: {
                plugins: {
                    tailwindcss: {},
                    autoprefixer: {},
                },
            }
        }
    },
    css: ['@/assets/css/main.css',],
})
```

```
 ERROR  Cannot split a chunk that has already been edited (119:17 – "', { enumerable: false, value: true })   14:55:38
return __returned__
}

})
import { createElementVNode as _createElementVNode, renderList as _renderList, Fragment as _Fragment, openBlock as _openBlock, createElementBlock as _createElementBlock, createBlock as _createBlock, normalizeClass as _normalizeClass, createTextVNode as _createTextVNode, createStaticVNode as _createStaticVNode } from "vue"

const _hoisted_1 = { class: "app m-0 h-full flex flex-col items-center" }
const _hoisted_2 = { class: "header" }
const _hoisted_3 = { class: "header-items" }
const _hoisted_4 = { class: "flex flex-1 h-fit" }
const _hoisted_5 = /*#__PURE__*/_createElementVNode("h1", { class: "font-semibold text-3xl" }, "Wordle", -1)
const _hoisted_6 = { class: "flex flex-1 h-fit justify-end" }
const _hoisted_7 = { class: "game w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center" }
const _hoisted_8 = { class: "card-list grid grid-cols-3 w-full overflow-hidden" }
const _hoisted_9 = {
  ref: "info-box",
  class: "overlay"
}
const _hoisted_10 = { class: "boxx p-5" }
const _hoisted_11 = { class: "flex items-center mb-4" }
const _hoisted_12 = /*#__PURE__*/_createElementVNode("h2", { class: "flex-1 font-semibold" }, "HOW TO PLAY", -1)
const _hoisted_13 = /*#__PURE__*/_createStaticVNode("<p class=\"font-light text-sm mb-2\">Inspired by <a href=\"https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html\">Wordle</a> and <a href=\"https://letterboxd.com/tobiasandersen2/list/random-movie-roulette/\">this list</a>.</p><p class=\"font-light text-sm mb-2\">Every day there&#39;s a new random set of films from the 2000 most popular on Letterboxd.</p><p class=\"font-light text-sm mb-2\">After you select a film, you can choose to select another, but you can&#39;t go back. If you want to stop, just click confirm</p>", 3)
const _hoisted_16 = {
  ref: "settings-box",
  class: "overlay"
}
const _hoisted_17 = { class: "boxx p-5" }
const _hoisted_18 = { class: "flex items-center mb-4" }
const _hoisted_19 = /*#__PURE__*/_createElementVNode("h2", { class: "flex-1 font-semibold" }, "SETTINGS", -1)
const _hoisted_20 = /*#__PURE__*/_createElementVNode("p", { class: "font-light text-sm mb-2" }, "Settings and new sets of films coming in the future!", -1)

function _sfc_render(_ctx, _cache, $props, $setup, $data, $options) {
  return (_openBlock(), _createElementBlock("div", _hoisted_1, [
    _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_2, [
      _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_3, [
        _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_4, [
          _createElementVNode("img", {
            src: "/__NUXT_BASE__/assets/info.svg",
            class: "icon",
            onClick: _cache[0] || (_cache[0] = $event => ($options.open(_ctx.info-_ctx.box)))
          })
        ]),
        _hoisted_5,
        _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_6, [
          _createElementVNode("img", {
            src: "/__NUXT_BASE__/assets/settings.svg",
            class: "icon",
            onClick: _cache[1] || (_cache[1] = $event => ($options.open(_ctx.settings-_ctx.box)))
          })
        ])
      ])
    ]),
    _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_7, [
      _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_8, [
        (_openBlock(true), _createElementBlock(_Fragment, null, _renderList($data.films, (film, i) => {
          return (_openBlock(), _createBlock($setup["Card"], {
            film: film,
            i: i,
            key: i,
            onFlip: $options.grayFilm
          }, null, 8, ["film", "i", "onFlip"]))
        }), 128))
      ]),
      _createElementVNode("div", {
        class: _normalizeClass(["button my-6", { '")


 ERROR  [nuxt:dynamic-base-path] Cannot split a chunk that has already been edited (119:17 – "', { enumerable: false, value: true })
return __returned__
}

})
import { createElementVNode as _createElementVNode, renderList as _renderList, Fragment as _Fragment, openBlock as _openBlock, createElementBlock as _createElementBlock, createBlock as _createBlock, normalizeClass as _normalizeClass, createTextVNode as _createTextVNode, createStaticVNode as _createStaticVNode } from "vue"

const _hoisted_1 = { class: "app m-0 h-full flex flex-col items-center" }
const _hoisted_2 = { class: "header" }
const _hoisted_3 = { class: "header-items" }
const _hoisted_4 = { class: "flex flex-1 h-fit" }
const _hoisted_5 = /*#__PURE__*/_createElementVNode("h1", { class: "font-semibold text-3xl" }, "Wordle", -1)
const _hoisted_6 = { class: "flex flex-1 h-fit justify-end" }
const _hoisted_7 = { class: "game w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center" }
const _hoisted_8 = { class: "card-list grid grid-cols-3 w-full overflow-hidden" }
const _hoisted_9 = {
  ref: "info-box",
  class: "overlay"
}
const _hoisted_10 = { class: "boxx p-5" }
const _hoisted_11 = { class: "flex items-center mb-4" }
const _hoisted_12 = /*#__PURE__*/_createElementVNode("h2", { class: "flex-1 font-semibold" }, "HOW TO PLAY", -1)
const _hoisted_13 = /*#__PURE__*/_createStaticVNode("<p class=\"font-light text-sm mb-2\">Inspired by <a href=\"https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html\">Wordle</a> and <a href=\"https://letterboxd.com/tobiasandersen2/list/random-movie-roulette/\">this list</a>.</p><p class=\"font-light text-sm mb-2\">Every day there&#39;s a new random set of films from the 2000 most popular on Letterboxd.</p><p class=\"font-light text-sm mb-2\">After you select a film, you can choose to select another, but you can&#39;t go back. If you want to stop, just click confirm</p>", 3)
const _hoisted_16 = {
  ref: "settings-box",
  class: "overlay"
}
const _hoisted_17 = { class: "boxx p-5" }
const _hoisted_18 = { class: "flex items-center mb-4" }
const _hoisted_19 = /*#__PURE__*/_createElementVNode("h2", { class: "flex-1 font-semibold" }, "SETTINGS", -1)
const _hoisted_20 = /*#__PURE__*/_createElementVNode("p", { class: "font-light text-sm mb-2" }, "Settings and new sets of films coming in the future!", -1)

function _sfc_render(_ctx, _cache, $props, $setup, $data, $options) {
  return (_openBlock(), _createElementBlock("div", _hoisted_1, [
    _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_2, [
      _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_3, [
        _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_4, [
          _createElementVNode("img", {
            src: "/__NUXT_BASE__/assets/info.svg",
            class: "icon",
            onClick: _cache[0] || (_cache[0] = $event => ($options.open(_ctx.info-_ctx.box)))
          })
        ]),
        _hoisted_5,
        _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_6, [
          _createElementVNode("img", {
            src: "/__NUXT_BASE__/assets/settings.svg",
            class: "icon",
            onClick: _cache[1] || (_cache[1] = $event => ($options.open(_ctx.settings-_ctx.box)))
          })
        ])
      ])
    ]),
    _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_7, [
      _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_8, [
        (_openBlock(true), _createElementBlock(_Fragment, null, _renderList($data.films, (film, i) => {
          return (_openBlock(), _createBlock($setup["Card"], {
            film: film,
            i: i,
            key: i,
            onFlip: $options.grayFilm
          }, null, 8, ["film", "i", "onFlip"]))
        }), 128))
      ]),
      _createElementVNode("div", {
        class: _normalizeClass(["button my-6", { '")
file: C:/Users/maia/Desktop/lboxdroulette/nuxt-app/app.vue


 ERROR  Cannot split a chunk that has already been edited (119:17 – "', { enumerable: false, value: true })   14:55:38
return __returned__
}

})
import { createElementVNode as _createElementVNode, renderList as _renderList, Fragment as _Fragment, openBlock as _openBlock, createElementBlock as _createElementBlock, createBlock as _createBlock, normalizeClass as _normalizeClass, createTextVNode as _createTextVNode, createStaticVNode as _createStaticVNode } from "vue"

const _hoisted_1 = { class: "app m-0 h-full flex flex-col items-center" }
const _hoisted_2 = { class: "header" }
const _hoisted_3 = { class: "header-items" }
const _hoisted_4 = { class: "flex flex-1 h-fit" }
const _hoisted_5 = /*#__PURE__*/_createElementVNode("h1", { class: "font-semibold text-3xl" }, "Wordle", -1)
const _hoisted_6 = { class: "flex flex-1 h-fit justify-end" }
const _hoisted_7 = { class: "game w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center" }
const _hoisted_8 = { class: "card-list grid grid-cols-3 w-full overflow-hidden" }
const _hoisted_9 = {
  ref: "info-box",
  class: "overlay"
}
const _hoisted_10 = { class: "boxx p-5" }
const _hoisted_11 = { class: "flex items-center mb-4" }
const _hoisted_12 = /*#__PURE__*/_createElementVNode("h2", { class: "flex-1 font-semibold" }, "HOW TO PLAY", -1)
const _hoisted_13 = /*#__PURE__*/_createStaticVNode("<p class=\"font-light text-sm mb-2\">Inspired by <a href=\"https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html\">Wordle</a> and <a href=\"https://letterboxd.com/tobiasandersen2/list/random-movie-roulette/\">this list</a>.</p><p class=\"font-light text-sm mb-2\">Every day there&#39;s a new random set of films from the 2000 most popular on Letterboxd.</p><p class=\"font-light text-sm mb-2\">After you select a film, you can choose to select another, but you can&#39;t go back. If you want to stop, just click confirm</p>", 3)
const _hoisted_16 = {
  ref: "settings-box",
  class: "overlay"
}
const _hoisted_17 = { class: "boxx p-5" }
const _hoisted_18 = { class: "flex items-center mb-4" }
const _hoisted_19 = /*#__PURE__*/_createElementVNode("h2", { class: "flex-1 font-semibold" }, "SETTINGS", -1)
const _hoisted_20 = /*#__PURE__*/_createElementVNode("p", { class: "font-light text-sm mb-2" }, "Settings and new sets of films coming in the future!", -1)

function _sfc_render(_ctx, _cache, $props, $setup, $data, $options) {
  return (_openBlock(), _createElementBlock("div", _hoisted_1, [
    _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_2, [
      _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_3, [
        _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_4, [
          _createElementVNode("img", {
            src: "/__NUXT_BASE__/assets/info.svg",
            class: "icon",
            onClick: _cache[0] || (_cache[0] = $event => ($options.open(_ctx.info-_ctx.box)))
          })
        ]),
        _hoisted_5,
        _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_6, [
          _createElementVNode("img", {
            src: "/__NUXT_BASE__/assets/settings.svg",
            class: "icon",
            onClick: _cache[1] || (_cache[1] = $event => ($options.open(_ctx.settings-_ctx.box)))
          })
        ])
      ])
    ]),
    _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_7, [
      _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_8, [
        (_openBlock(true), _createElementBlock(_Fragment, null, _renderList($data.films, (film, i) => {
          return (_openBlock(), _createBlock($setup["Card"], {
            film: film,
            i: i,
            key: i,
            onFlip: $options.grayFilm
          }, null, 8, ["film", "i", "onFlip"]))
        }), 128))
      ]),
      _createElementVNode("div", {
        class: _normalizeClass(["button my-6", { '")

  return __returned__
  }

  })
  import { createElementVNode as _createElementVNode, renderList as _renderList, Fragment as _Fragment, openBlock as _openBlock, createElementBlock as _createElementBlock, createBlock as _createBlock, normalizeClass as _normalizeClass, createTextVNode as _createTextVNode, createStaticVNode as _createStaticVNode } from "vue"

  const _hoisted_1 = { class: "app m-0 h-full flex flex-col items-center" }
  const _hoisted_2 = { class: "header" }
  const _hoisted_3 = { class: "header-items" }
  const _hoisted_4 = { class: "flex flex-1 h-fit" }
  const _hoisted_5 = /*#__PURE__*/_createElementVNode("h1", { class: "font-semibold text-3xl" }, "Wordle", -1)
  const _hoisted_6 = { class: "flex flex-1 h-fit justify-end" }
  const _hoisted_7 = { class: "game w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center" }
  const _hoisted_8 = { class: "card-list grid grid-cols-3 w-full overflow-hidden" }
  const _hoisted_9 = {
  ref: "info-box",
  class: "overlay"
  }
  const _hoisted_10 = { class: "boxx p-5" }
  const _hoisted_11 = { class: "flex items-center mb-4" }
  const _hoisted_12 = /*#__PURE__*/_createElementVNode("h2", { class: "flex-1 font-semibold" }, "HOW TO PLAY", -1)
  const _hoisted_13 = /*#__PURE__*/_createStaticVNode("<p class=\"font-light text-sm mb-2\">Inspired by <a href=\"https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html\">Wordle</a> and <a href=\"https://letterboxd.com/tobiasandersen2/list/random-movie-roulette/\">this list</a>.</p><p class=\"font-light text-sm mb-2\">Every day there&#39;s a new random set of films from the 2000 most popular on Letterboxd.</p><p class=\"font-light text-sm mb-2\">After you select a film, you can choose to select another, but you can&#39;t go back. If you want to stop, just click confirm</p>", 3)
  const _hoisted_16 = {
  ref: "settings-box",
  class: "overlay"
  }
  const _hoisted_17 = { class: "boxx p-5" }
  const _hoisted_18 = { class: "flex items-center mb-4" }
  const _hoisted_19 = /*#__PURE__*/_createElementVNode("h2", { class: "flex-1 font-semibold" }, "SETTINGS", -1)
  const _hoisted_20 = /*#__PURE__*/_createElementVNode("p", { class: "font-light text-sm mb-2" }, "Settings and new sets of films coming in the future!", -1)

  function _sfc_render(_ctx, _cache, $props, $setup, $data, $options) {
  return (_openBlock(), _createElementBlock("div", _hoisted_1, [
  _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_2, [
  _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_3, [
  _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_4, [
  _createElementVNode("img", {
  src: "/__NUXT_BASE__/assets/info.svg",
  class: "icon",
  onClick: _cache[0] || (_cache[0] = $event => ($options.open(_ctx.info-_ctx.box)))
  })
  ]),
  _hoisted_5,
  _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_6, [
  _createElementVNode("img", {
  src: "/__NUXT_BASE__/assets/settings.svg",
  class: "icon",
  onClick: _cache[1] || (_cache[1] = $event => ($options.open(_ctx.settings-_ctx.box)))
  })
  ])
  ])
  ]),
  _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_7, [
  _createElementVNode("div", _hoisted_8, [
  (_openBlock(true), _createElementBlock(_Fragment, null, _renderList($data.films, (film, i) => {
  return (_openBlock(), _createBlock($setup["Card"], {
  film: film,
  i: i,
  key: i,
  onFlip: $options.grayFilm
  }, null, 8, ["film", "i", "onFlip"]))
  }), 128))
  ]),
  _createElementVNode("div", {
  class: _normalizeClass(["button my-6", { '")
  at MagicString._splitChunk (/C:/Users/maia/Desktop/lboxdroulette/nuxt-app/node_modules/@nuxt/vite-builder/node_modules/magic-string/dist/magic-string.es.mjs:895:10)
  at MagicString._split (/C:/Users/maia/Desktop/lboxdroulette/nuxt-app/node_modules/@nuxt/vite-builder/node_modules/magic-string/dist/magic-string.es.mjs:885:43)
  at MagicString.overwrite (/C:/Users/maia/Desktop/lboxdroulette/nuxt-app/node_modules/@nuxt/vite-builder/node_modules/magic-string/dist/magic-string.es.mjs:668:8)
  at /C:/Users/maia/Desktop/lboxdroulette/nuxt-app/node_modules/@nuxt/vite-builder/node_modules/magic-string/dist/magic-string.es.mjs:1052:11
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at MagicString.replace (/C:/Users/maia/Desktop/lboxdroulette/nuxt-app/node_modules/@nuxt/vite-builder/node_modules/magic-string/dist/magic-string.es.mjs:1050:12)
  at Object.transform (/C:/Users/maia/Desktop/lboxdroulette/nuxt-app/node_modules/@nuxt/vite-builder/dist/index.mjs:200:11)
  at node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:22834:37

error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: neither, just a personal project, i used this https://letterboxd.com/tobiasandersen2/list/random-movie-roulette/ to find movies before, and wanted to make a site that did kind of the same lol

Comment: We just saw the same issue with an unresolved merge conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the title is coming from the fact that

```js
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
```

is redundant in a Nuxt project, the rest is *probably* coming from the imports done like

```js
import csv from "./assets/film_list.csv";
```

rather than

```js
import csv from "~/assets/film_list.csv";
```

More info is available on [the documentation](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/features/assets#assets-directory).

---

Alright, I just spent **too much time** cleaning your project.
There is quite a lot of things done wrongly there.

So yeah, not sure if this is somehow listable but here is a diff (without counting the additions) to have something clean and working.

[image]

The repo is available here: https://github.com/kissu/lboxd-roulette/tree/main

Answer (score 1):

Following the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72038050/8816585) previously given to you, I've used [`@rollup/plugin-dsv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-dsv) even tho [other transforms](https://github.com/vitejs/awesome-vite#transformers) also exist (maybe more flexible and with even better support).

So, after a `yarn add -D @rollup/plugin-dsv`, I've set this configuration in `nuxt.config.ts`

```js
// @ts-nocheck
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'
import dsv from '@rollup/plugin-dsv'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  vite: {
    plugins: [dsv()]
  }
})
```

As you can see, you can pass the vite configuration directly to the Nuxt file.

Then, with the following `film_list.csv` file

```
name,year,href,src
Parasite,2019,parasite-2019,film-poster/4/2/6/4/0/6/426406-parasite-0-460-0-690-crop.jpg
```

It works fine like this

```html
<script setup>
import csv from './film_list.csv'
console.log('csv', csv)
</script>

<template>
  <pre>{{ csv }}</pre>
</template>
```

And is also generating perfectly well with `yarn generate`

As you can see a live version on Netlify

[image]

Here is a [Github repo](https://github.com/kissu/n3-dsv) reproducing a working setup.